# Как выбрать столбцы в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Хочу попробовать сделать классификатор документов используя этот датасет https://www.kaggle.com/olegbartenyev/doc-cls/discussion .
При открытии пытаюсь сделать столбцы , там где содержится символ # .
Но ничего не выходит
Делал через
read_csv

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы без __явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел данные. Там же всего два столбца, проще каждую строку просто через `partition(' ')` разделить, прочитав эти данные как обычный текстовый файл. `Pandas` вам не нужен, у вас первый столбец - это категория в качестве целевой переменной, а дальше идёт текст, который вам нужно будет как-то обрабатывать, чтобы сделать из него признаки. Библиотека `Pandas` тут не нужна от слова совсем - вам просто нечего выбирать в этих данных с её помощью, с такими данными проще обращаться как с двумя отдельными списками.

`Pandas` хорош для табличных данных, если столбцы разделены каким-то символом. Тут нет такой структуры - пробел отделяет первую колонку, но дальше он спокойно используется в тексте как обычный символ, поэтому он не может служить нормальным разделителем как в `csv` файлах.